# ASP.Net Web Forms Identity\OWIN Login Page Access Issues

Tags: asp.net, owin, identity, .net-4.7

I have recently been re-working a web form application from .net2.0 to .net4.7 and decide to add Identity and OWIn for local and social authentication.

I create a new web forms app and then copied the account, app_start and models folders over to the existing app as well as the startup.vb file.

Now all this is OK and the app compiles without issue however whenever we try to login using /Accoount/Login itsimply redirects us back to the default.aspx page in the root of the app.

there is a web.config file in the Account folder and it looks like this, although i do not think this is the issue:

```
<configuration>
<location path="Manage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Although this allows authenticated access to manage.aspx all other files in the account folder should be anonymous access but something is redirecting away from login.aspx and I cannot figure out what?

Anyone come across this?

Comment: In web.config, do you have are you using forms authentication, if so, it is set to which login form url?

Comment: No forms authentication as this is an identity/OWIN setup so in the root web.config file I have the following: <authentication mode="None" />

Comment: I have added a web.config file to the root of public folders allowing all users access both authenticated and anonymous and this has not helped as some of these files i.e. css, scripts, etc are used in restricted pages.

Comment: Further investigation in FireFox DevTools shows a 302 redirect happening?!?!? cannot see anywhere in code where this would take place and why?